# Signed APK crashes on android 5.0

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat, android-actionbaractivity

I updated an Android project to Android 5.0 and everything is fine when running directly from Eclipse in Genymotion Simulator. But when I create a signed APK and upload that, it crashes. The signed APK works on Android 4.0 Simulator, but not on 5.0. 
The AppCompat Library is linked with the project in Android > Library.

In the AndroidManifest.xml I have declared:

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

My base activity extends **android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity**. And this is the error I see in logcat when running on 5.0:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myapp.mypackage, PID: 1414
     java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "android.support.v7.app.ActionBar ol.a()"
    at ol.b(SourceFile:123)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.getSupportActionBar(SourceFile:73)
    at com.myapp.mypackage.StartActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:91)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

What could cause this or what is the difference between running directly and installing, except the signing?

Thank you very much, your help is appreciated!

Comment: is the support library up-to-date? (21.0.3)

Comment: Yes, I update all SDK tools regularly.

Comment: Are you using `Proguard`? Also, why minSdK of 11?

Comment: Yes, I am using Proguard, but I cannot find any configuration there what would conflict with Android versions.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? How exactly have you fixed it?

Comment: Yes, I turned Proguard off. I don't know what exactly did to make it crash, but the app still worked without Proguard. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Delete Eclipse and install `Android Studio`. ADT plugin is no longer supported by Google.
2. You should always target latest Android version (current latest is 22)
3. You should use latest `v7 appcompat library` (current latest is 22.2.0)
4. You should extend your activity from `AppCompatActivity`

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with Samsung's custom android and zipalign. While using zipalign, remove the -z parameter. This apk should work.